Unable to change hyperlink Foreground when DataGridRow is Selected
I am modifying a program that binds a search into a DataGrid.
Expected Behavior is that when the grid is selected, all of the foreground for the text in those columns turn white to contrast,  then when it's deselected  it turns back to Black.
I added in a static column with a hyperlink in it. I am unable to get it to switch over to white :
I am predefining the style, however the hyperlink is wrapped in a TextBlock
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock"
           x:Key="TextBlockStyle">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{StaticResource PopupForegroundBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
                Value="18" />
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping"
                Value="Wrap" />
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth"
                Value="125" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Hyperlink" x:Key="DataGridHyperlinkStyle">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <converter:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>


  <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Other Location QOH"
                                            Width="1*"
                                            IsReadOnly="True">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Padding="5">
                                        <Hyperlink Click="otherQohHyperlink_Click" TextDecorations="None" Tag="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridHyperlinkStyle}"> 
                                            Other Location QOH Search 
                                         </Hyperlink>   
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>


The DataTrigger works.

Turns out that the data trigger is working, thank you @emoacht  :  I also found that I'm linking it to an event that is not triggering, so I'm binding to an update event for the previous data link and that should fix the issue.
